# NSTableView compound columns in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nstableview

I have a table with a column for item names and a column for a check box cell.
I have researched and found only iOS specific answers (which are not adoptable to OS X).

I use an array controller to display the item names and check box cells in a NSMutableDictionary (all of course inside a NSArray for the controller).

- Problem: The problem is, I can only bind a value of check box cells once, and that is firstly to the array controller. It shows the item names correctly and also displays check box cells this way, but it does not save the check box cell's value on relaunch (to no surprise).

Now since the values of each column are bound together I cannot separate them.
I researched and found that "Shared User Defaults Controller" or NSUserDefaults could be used for both columns for NSTableView, but how do I then fill the table programmatically?

After connecting the dataSource and binding the NSTableView content "MixedValues" to "Shared User Defaults Controller" I got it as far as this:

```
- (void) myItemListFunction
{
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < myItemList.count; i++)
    {
        [rows addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[myItemList objectAtIndex:i], @"MyItemList", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CheckboxCell"], @"CheckboxCell", nil]];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:rows forKey:@"MixedValues"];
    }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

- Output: Checkbox cells are shown, but cannot be checked, item names are not displayed, but the rows are correct in number

**EDIT1:** I found out through NSLog, that the problem seems to be the check box cell code, because the checkbox bool isn't shown:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"CheckboxCell"], @"CheckboxCell"
```

I somehow need to get the for-loop variable i into the boolForKey I figure, but how...

**Edit2:** Using this gives at least a bool inside the NSLog:

```
[rows addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[myItemList objectAtIndex:i], @"MyItemList", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"CheckBoxCell", nil]];
```

**Edit3:** Now I got it so far as to save the state of the checkbox cell, however it uses the entire array of of objects when using arrayForKey. What I now need is to get it to somehow use objectAtIndex:i for each item inside the model key path "CheckboxCell". And it still does not show the items of MyItemList...

**Edit4:** Now it seems this code would generate just once checkbox, but it goes along the lines of what I am trying to achieve:

```
NSArray *arrayList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"Check"];
arrayList = @[@"0"];

[rows2 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[directoryList objectAtIndex:i], @"Logs", arrayList, @"Check", nil]];
```

What needs to be done is get the @"Check" in the last line to include objectAtIndex:i ...

Comment: And how does NSUserDefaults come into play?  What is myItemList?  And how do you store checkbox status values?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @BlueTomato NSUserDefaults should as described in the problem store the state of the checkbox and the item names list myItemList, and checkbox status values I assumed are stored by binding the content of the NSTableView to "MixedValues" of "Shared User Defaults Controller". And myItemList is simply a list of item names, like a shopping list for example.

Comment: Why don't you just use NSMutableArray with NSMutableDictionary to store item names or whatever along with checkbox status values?

Comment: Because they would be gone after a relaunch of the application.

Comment: It'll take a few lines of code to save an NSMutableArray to an XML file.  But if that's what you want, I have nothing more to say.

Comment: Thanks @BlueTomato I would still receive the same result, wouldn't I, because the columns have compound values i.e. they are bound together?